How is a constant speed of the Engine driven hydraulic pumps maintained (or isn’t it)?
As the N2 rotation speed varies, the accessory gearbox speed also varies and some components like the generators need the constant speed drive (CSD) to maintain the needed speed (unless variable frequency generators are used). How does it exactly work for the hydraulic pumps that are installed on the gearbox ?

Hydraulic pumps are driven directly
Their rotation speed is a direct function of the engine rotation speed. Hydraulic pumps therefore incorporate a solution to maintain a constant system pressure under the dynamically varying engine rotation speed and hydraulic fluid demand. The solution depends on the type of pump.
Spur Gear pump
During most phases of operation, this pump tries to supply the system with more fluid than it needs. A relief valve returns the excess fluid to the reservoir, thus maintaining system pressure.
Axial Piston pump
Here, the swash plate angle is varied to maintain the system pressure. The swash plate angle is controlled by a spring loaded actuator known as the servo piston, which is supplied directly by the pump itself. If the system pressure starts rising (the engine accelerates or the fluid demand reduces), the servo piston forces the swash plate to a finer angle, thereby reducing the pressure. Conversely, if the system pressure falls, the spring forces the swash plate to a coarser angle, thereby recovering the pressure.  Thus, a constant system pressure is maintained.

Thank you very much for the information!

There are also pressurized accumulators for evening out pressure when demand or RPM fluctuates.
